# parrot and owl probability

Tags: probability

> Jacky bought $2$ cages of birds: cage $(1)$st contain $5$ parrots and $1$ owl and cage $(2)$nd contain $6$ parrots, One day Jacky forgets to lock 
>    both cages and $2$ birds fly from  cage $1$ st to cage $2$ nd. Then $2$ birds flow back from cage $2$nd to cage $1$st. Assume that all birds have equal chances of flying, then probability that owl is still in cage $1$st, is?

what I tried

probability of $2$ birds flew from cage $1$st to cage $2$nd is

$\displaystyle \frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}$

and probability that $2$ birds flew from cage $2$nd to cage $1$st is $\displaystyle 1$

So required probability is $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}\cdot 1 = \frac{2}{3}$

Help me to solve to please

answer given is $\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 3):

The owl moved to cage $2$ if it flew there and didn’t return. The probability to fly there was $\frac26=\frac13$, and the probability not to return was $1-\frac28=\frac34$. Thus the probability that the owl moved to cage $2$ is $\frac13\cdot\frac34=\frac14$. The probability that it’s still (or again) in cage $1$ is the complement, $1-\frac14=\frac34$.